# Hashtag urls in mobile devices? How do they work?

Tags: mobile, anchor, hashtag

Ok, probably a stupid question. But here goes... I know on regular websites a hashtag is an anchor to an element on the page, however, how does this work in mobile devices?  It seems to me that mobile devices can use hashtags to slide to another section on the same page, sort of like another page.

How do urls work like that in mobile devices??  I've been to the jquerymobile.com site and noticed the webapp builder on the homepage, offers the ability to change features to slide, slideup, slidedown, fade, pop, etc. etc., however, the only URL to choose from is always "HOME" for these features.  And home points to `#page1`, which is odd that it has a hashtag in it.  How do mobile devices work with these hashtags?  More importantly, how do I add the ability to slide to that hashtag, as in the way jquerymobile.com implies in the webapp builder?

I've tried doing my own research on this via google, but no luck, as `mobile hashtags` keeps bringing up other results, not what I am asking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between handling of the hash parts of URL in desktop vs. mobile browsers. The key point is that Javascript has access to the URL, including the hash part, and can do any programmatic thing based on the contents of the URL. So if the page author wants to slide in another section in response to changing the hash part of the URL, they can do that. People do the same thing on "desktop" sites, too.

Comment: Ok, but the jquerymobile.com webapp doesn't give you the ability to create more pages, so why include a dropdown for buttons with the only option in it as "HOME", which is `#page1`?  Is that stupid, or am I missing something?  Also, how can I slide the page to the left and slide in content to the right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything specifically about jquerymobile.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, and thanks!  That is what I thought, but just wanted to be sure!